# How to read a word file in web browser using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word

I have a message page in my project. The employees can send and receive messages with attachments. Attached file may be word, pdf or any image. Then when the attachment is clicked it should open in read mode (something happens like gmail attachments). Here when I open word, it gets downloaded. But actually I don't need to display it, but to open in read-only mode.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Google docs provides a doc viewer which shows remote documents files on the fly. You just need to provide the url and it will generate the link and embed code. You can also generate dynamic links

[Google docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

Comment: Hi, it has some limit of the number of documents to display, after that limit documents just don't display. just error message is displayed.

Comment: Displaying the word file in browser is subject to browser support rather than some online applications like google drive, onedrive supports online documents to be displayed in browser. So just upload your docs in dedicated account and you can get a share link of that document from there. Use this link for loading/displaying word file in browser

Comment: you can check the bandwidth limit [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)